# Assign user input to a variable in Python

Tags: python, variables, textbox

I am having some problem when trying to get the input text and assign them to variable in Python. Here are my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *
fields = 'Last Name', 'First Name', 'Job', 'Country'

def fetch(entries):
   for entry in entries:
      field = entry[0]
      text  = entry[1].get()
      print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text)) 

def makeform(root, fields):
   entries = []
   for field in fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
      entries.append((field, ent))
   return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   ents = makeform(root, fields)
   root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))   
   b1 = Button(root, text='Show',
          command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e)))
   b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   b2 = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
   b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   root.mainloop()
```

When I ran this, it managed to print out first and last name, job and country respectively. But I am using a loop to loop through the entries. I was thinking if it is possible to get each of them and assign to a variable because I need the values to do some validation and SQL statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible. So what is your question?

Comment: I am trying to get the input for each fields and store them into different variables according.

Comment: Still there is no question. Anyway try accessing `ents[0][1]`,`ents[1][1]` etc in given code

Comment: Sorry but what I meant is yes, it did loop thru entries and printed out. But from the loop there, what should I do to make it in a way like for example entry to last name and I store to a variable named 'lastName', job entry for job variable etc.

Comment: as earlier, by accessing respective entries in `ents`. So do `lastName=ents[0][1]`

Answer (score 0):

Make `entries` a global variable. If there are more than 4 fields in `entries`, maybe instead of using a nested list where each item has 2 fields (a field, and text), you should make each item hold the four fields (first name, last name, job, country). This way each entry in `entries` will have all its data in one item. You can just hardcode the order of the four fields and access `entries` accordingly for your validation or SQL statements: `entries[x][y]`, where `x` indicates the "row" of data and `y` would indicate the exact field (0: last name, 1: first name, 2: job, 3: country).

You wouldn't even need your `fetch(entries)` function, unless you still wanted to print them out.

Hope this helps. Happy coding!